# Store numbers and compare based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently working to learn Python 3.5 from scratch and thoroughly enjoying the process. latest thing is to write a basic program that does the following..

- Asks user to think of a number between 1 and 100
- Guesses what it is
- Asks user to enter '1' if too low, '3' if too high and '2' if
  correct
- Provides a new number based on that user input
- Limits itself to 10 tries before quitting in shame
- Celebrates when it gets it right

Now I THINK I've got it all working minus the higher / lower feature. My question is this.

*Note* This differs from other questions on the topic because I do not want to enter any numbers for the PC to work on. Also want to generate pseudo-random numbers that are limited to within given values for subsequent guesses from the PC. Not increment.

"How can I implement a feature that looks at the var 'guess' and modifies it to be higher or lower based on user input while keeping it above 0 and below 100".

**Code:**

```
import random  

print("\tWelcome to the psychic computer")
print("\nI want you to think of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("I will try to guess it in 10 or less tries.\n")
print("\n Press 1 for a lower guess, 3 for a higher one and 2 if I get it       right\n")

tries = int(1)

guess = random.randint(1, 100)
print("\nI guess ", + guess, " Is this correct?")


while tries < 10:
    feedback = int (input("\nEnter 1 if too high, 3 if too low or 2 if bang   on\n\n"))
    tries += 1
    if feedback == 1:
        print("Balls! Guess I need to go Higher will", + guess, + "do?")

    elif feedback == 3:
        print("\nSh*te! Lower it is then...")

    elif feedback == 2:
        print("YEEAAAHH BOYEEEE! Told you I was phychic.")
        input("\nHit enter to quit")
        end

    elif feedback != (1,2,3):
        print("Not a valid guess. Try again.")
        break

    if tries >= 9:
        print("\nSh*t, guess I'm not so psychic after all")
    input("\nHit enter to exit")
```

Comment: Your `if` and `elif` blocks are outside the `while` loop. Is that how your actual code is, or is it just an error copying your code over?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Guess the number game optimization (user creates number, computer guesses)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877870/guess-the-number-game-optimization-user-creates-number-computer-guesses)

Comment: That's an error copying the code over. Apologies.

Comment: Please correct it, then.

Comment: Done. I may be missing something in the other post but it looks like none of the suggested answers give a random guess between the previous number and 0 or 100 - they seem to increment which I'm keen to avoid if possible. I also want to avoid typing the answer into the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like a binary search. Use a low_number and a high_number to calculate a guess by taking the middle value of the two. These can initially be set 0 and 100. You should also keep track of your last guess. If you last guess was too low, you can set your low_number equal to that guess+1. If your last guess was too high, you can set your high_number to that guess-1.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what I have so far. It works in that it will respond with (semi) random higher or lower guesses based on user input but does not yet store the original guess as a reference. I will look at that tomorrow. Thanks again for the suggestions.

BTW once working I plan to use math and come up with a solution that always gets it right inside x amount of tries..

```
    import random  

    print("\tWelcome to the psychic computer")
    print("\nI want you to think of a number between 1 and 100.")
    print("I will try to guess it in 10 or less tries.\n")
    print("\n Press 1 for a higher guess, 3 for a lower one and 2 if I get it    right\n")

    tries = int()
    guess = random.randint(1, 100)
    high_number = int(100 - guess)
    low_number = int(1 + guess)

    print("\nI guess ", + guess, " Is this correct?")

    while tries < 10:

    feedback = int (input("\nEnter 1 to go higher, 3 to go lower or 2 if bang    on\n\n"))
    tries += 1
    if feedback == 1:
        guess = random.randint(high_number, 100)
        print("Balls! Guess I need to go Higher how about", + guess)

        elif feedback == 3:
            guess = random.randint(1, low_number)
            print("\nSh*te! Lower it is then... what about", + guess)    

        elif feedback == 2:
            print("YEEAAAHH BOYEEEE! Told you I was phychic.")
            input("\nHit enter to quit")
            end

        elif feedback != (1,2,3):
            input("Not a valid guess. Try again.")
            break

if tries >= 9:
    print("\nSh*t, guess I'm not so psychic after all")
input("\nHit enter to exit")
```